# Java, mi programa no termina de correr al llamar un método que usa InputDialog (JOptionPane)

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo Java. En cierto programa hago invocación a un método para obtener ciertos datos a través de un Input Dialogue en un JOptionPane,

```
 package Formas;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 public abstract class Poligono {

//Atributos
protected float base, altura, perimetro, area;
//Métodos
public void getDatos(){
    int b=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese medida de la base: "));
    setBase(b);
    int h=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese medida de la altura: "));
    setAltura(h);
}

public void setBase(float base) {
    this.base = base;
}

public void setAltura(float altura) {
    this.altura = altura;
}

public float getBase() {
    return base;
}

public float getAltura() {
    return altura;
}

public abstract float calcArea();
public abstract void showDatos();
}
```

compila y funciona correctamente, pero la cosa es que quisiera que por consola de indicara el número de elementos y que posteriormente se hiciera la llamada al método en el que uso el input Dialogue para obtener los datos, mi problema es que al estar usado una entrada de datos con Scanner (Para hacer esto por consola) al momento de llamar al método para abrir el input Dialogue se queda cargando, en el NetBeans dice Running pero no pasa de ahí. Tampoco marca error de alguna excepción. Lo he logrado hacer funcionar pidiendo todas las cosas con Input Dialogues.

```
package Main;
import Formas.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int tdf, op;
    tdf=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese total de     poligonos: "));
    Poligono [] formas=new Poligono[tdf];
    op=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\tEscoja:\n\n1. Rectángulo\n2. Triángulo."));
    for (int i = 0; i < tdf; i++) {
        switch(op){
            case 1: formas[i]=new Rectangulo();break;
            case 2: formas[i]=new Triangulo();break;
        }
        formas[i].getDatos();
        formas[i].showDatos();
    }
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir si pido todos los datos a través de input Dialogues si funciona, pero si pido algunas cosas usando un Scanner y luego otras con el Input Dialogue, el programa no sigue corriendo.

```
package Main;
import Formas.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    int tdf, op;
    System.out.print("Ingrese el total de figuras: ");
    tdf=scan.nextInt();
    Poligono [] formas=new Poligono[tdf];
    for (int i = 0; i < tdf; i++) {
        System.out.print("\tEscoja:\n1. Rectángulo.\n2. Triángulo.\n\nOpción: ");
        op=scan.nextInt();
        switch(op){
            case 1: formas[i]=new Rectangulo();break;
            case 2: formas[i]=new Triangulo();break;
        }
        formas[i].getDatos();
        formas[i].showDatos();
    }
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea ? Si, ya verifique que también he importado el JOptionPane en la clase Main desde la cual llamo a es metodo que requiere un JOptionPane para su funcionamiento:P, quizá algo mal al momento de hacer el Switch ?

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo cuál es el problema. He compilado y ejecutado tu código y no encuentro el problema. Hice algunos cambios.

Tal vez se deba a que introduces algún valor erróneo.

**Main.java**

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main{

  public static void main(String[] args){
     int tdf, op;
    tdf=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese total de     poligonos: "));
    Poligono [] formas=new Poligono[tdf];
    op=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\tEscoja:\n\n1. Rectángulo\n2. Triángulo."));
    for (int i = 0; i < tdf; i++) {
        switch(op){
            case 1: formas[i]=new Rectangulo();break;
            case 2: formas[i]=new Triangulo();break;
            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\tOpcion no valida");break;
        }
        try{
    formas[i].getDatos();
    formas[i].showDatos();
  }catch(NullPointerException npe){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"\tOpcion no valida");
    System.exit(0);
  }

    }
  }

abstract class Poligono {

  //Atributos
  protected float base, altura, perimetro, area;
  //Métodos
  public void getDatos(){
      int b=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese medida de la base: "));
      setBase(b);
      int h=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese medida de la altura: "));
      setAltura(h);
  }

  public void setBase(float base) {
      this.base = base;
  }

  public void setAltura(float altura) {
      this.altura = altura;
  }

  public float getBase() {
      return base;
  }

  public float getAltura() {
      return altura;
  }

  public abstract float calcArea();
  public abstract void showDatos();
  }

class Triangulo extends Poligono{
  @Override
  public float calcArea(){
    return (this.base * this.altura)/2.0f;
  }

  @Override
  public void showDatos(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Area triangulo:\n"+this.calcArea());
  }
}

class Rectangulo extends Poligono{
  @Override
  public float calcArea(){
    return this.base*this.altura;
  }

  @Override
  public void showDatos(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Area rectangulo:\n"+this.calcArea());
  }
}

}
```